# Need help on a DC motor-PWM-SMPS setup (Does a PWM help overcome a DC motor's initial startup current surge?)

Tags: motor, dc, pwm, switch-mode-power-supply

I am trying to build a DIY one-way peristaltic pump with a 12V 100W DC motor 
(possible candidate :
https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-12V-100W-13000-15000rpm-775-motor-High-speed-Large-torque-DC-motor/352550303190)

which will be controlled by something like this PWM controller (10-50V, rated for 40A continuous & 60A max current)
(https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-10-55V-12V-24V-48V-30A-PWM-DC-Motor-Speed-Driver-Controller-Soft-Start-Switch/322616619257)

and will be powered by an SMPS supply such as this 12V 20A supply
(https://www.ebay.com/itm/AC-to-DC-240-Watt-12-24-Volt-20-10-Amp-LED-Driver-Switching-SMPS-Power-Supply/183703093948)

So my question is:

1. Will this setup work?
2. Is either of the PWM controller or SMPS supply overkill or underwhelming?
3. If this setup works, is it because of the PWM?

I ask because I've heard that DC motors draw 5~10 times their normal running current when they start up, so such setups involving SMPS power supplies may regard the initial current spike as a problem and may fail to 'turn on' properly, but a PWM helps with that problem.

But my understanding is that a PWM turns the flow of electricity on/off really fast so as to modulate the total electricity passed through but the current load (amps) stays untouched, so I'm not really sure what happens here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PWM appears to be a good choice as it has an unspecified SOFT START.

This means the duty cycle must start from 0 to the pot set value for some reasonable preset time such as >0.1 second by design assumptions for small motor start time.

Motors have an inductive where current rises with dI/dt = V/L so if dt starts at 0  then the soft start PWM ought to eliminate the or reduce the 10x start surge significantly.   Normally the start surge is due to the full voltage integrated to reach V+/Rs the coil resistance. But with a "soft-start" or ramped PWM duty cycle to set level by Pot, the average voltage starts low and the pump starts slow.  **I would expect this soft period to be at least 100ms but preferably >1s with only 10% of the starting current to avoid full power start of 10x rated current**.

If the Soft-start was done right for motors, with this 100W/12V = 8.2A motor a 15A PWM soft-start could work but I see it has a 30A rating which will run cooler.

Comment: Nice mustache Tony

Comment: Thank you! I have learned today :) There seems to be relatively few (cheap) controllers which claim to have the soft start function. Assuming that it is not a basic feature for such cheap $10 controllers, you're saying that the setup might not work if I used a similar controller but without the soft start function, right?